# Windows Forms: How to directly bind a Bitmap to a PictureBox?

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding, picturebox

I'm just trying to build a small C# .Net 4.0 application using Windows Forms (WPF I don't know at all, Windows Forms at least a little :-) ).

Is it possible to directly bind a `System.Drawing.Bitmap` object to the `Image` property of a `PictureBox`? I tried to use `PictureBox.DataBindings.Add(...)` but this doesn't seem to work.

How can I do this?

Thanks and best regards,
Oliver

Comment: If you have a bitmap, you can just assign it to the Image property of the PictureBox at runtime - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.image.aspx

Comment: What are you wishing to use as your datasource?

Answer (score 4):

This works for me:

```
Bitmap bitmapFromFile = new Bitmap("C:\\temp\\test.bmp");

pictureBox1.Image = bitmapFromFile;
```

or, in one line:

```
pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap("C:\\temp\\test.bmp");
```

You might be overcomplicating this - according to the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.image.aspx), you can simple assign the bitmap directly to the PictureBox.Image property.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
In fact I know this :) ... But it thought it's the ".Net way" to have data bindings!?

Comment: @Baldewin - it depends on your data model; data bindings are very common for actual data and are useful when you expect the underlying data to change - a control "bound" to this data will often automatically refresh. You *can* do this for image boxes but it is far less complex to manage the PictureBox.Image property directly; you can also control when the images are disposed too, which can be important in some circumtances. I've done this in the past with a file path to the image - so the DataBinding syntax for that is pictureBox.DataBindings.Add("ImageLocation", dataTable, "FilePath");

Comment: @Baldewin If you let me know the exact code you are using for your databinding then I'll try and help; be aware though that it's not necessary and is less common than setting the Image property (or the ImageLocation property) directly.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the PictureBox.DataBindings.Add(...)
The trick is to create a separate property on the object you are binding to to handle the conversion between null and and empty picture.

I did it this way.

In my form load I used

```
this.PictureBox.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Visible", this.bindingSource1, "HasPhoto", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));

this.PictureBox.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Image", this.bindingSource1, "MyPhoto",false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
```

In my object I have the following

```
[NotMapped]
public System.Drawing.Image MyPhoto
{
    get
    {            
        if (Photo == null)
        {
           return BlankImage;        
        }
        else
        {
           if (Photo.Length == 0)
           {
              return BlankImage;     
           }
           else
           {
              return byteArrayToImage(Photo);
           }
        }
    }
    set
    {
       if (value == null)
       {
          Photo = null;
       }
       else
       {
           if (value.Height == BlankImage.Height)  // cheating
           {
               Photo = null;
           }
           else
           {
               Photo = imageToByteArray(value);
           }
        }
    }
}

[NotMapped]
public Image BlankImage {
    get
    {
        return new Bitmap(1,1);
    }
}

public static byte[] imageToByteArray(Image imageIn)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    imageIn.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Gif);
    return ms.ToArray();     
}

public static Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
    Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
    return returnImage;
}
```

Comment: I have also used  pictureBox.DataBindings.Add( "Image", dataSource, dataMember,true);  The last parameteris important

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
System.Drawing.Bitmap bmp = new System.Drawing.Bitmap("yourfile.bmp");
picturebox1.Image = bmp;
```