# VB.Net using databindings with a picture box

Tags: vb.net, image, controls, datarepeater

A row, in a data table, iscalled `FirstImage` contains a url to an image file on a web server. I am trying to bind the data of this row to the image source of the picture box.

My current code:

```
For Each row As DataRow In ListData.Rows
    Dim ImageDecode = ser.Deserialize(Of PropertyImage())(row("Images"))
    row("FirstImage") = "http://rental.joshblease.co.uk/propertyimages/" & ImageDecode(0).Image
    'Returns http://rental.joshblease.co.uk/propertyimages/image1.jpg
Next row
TxtListName.DataBindings.Add("Text", ListData, "Name")
TxtListSlug.DataBindings.Add("Text", ListData, "Slug")
TxtListCreated.DataBindings.Add("Text", ListData, "Created")
ImgListItem.DataBindings.Add("Image", ListData, "FirstImage", True)
DataRepeater1.DataSource = ListData
```

But at the moment, the image is still blank. I have tried entering the location into a hidden textbox and copying the data over, but I can;t figure out how to use the controls in a data repeater.

This was the experimental copy from a hidden text box code:

```
If Me.DataRepeater1.ItemCount > 0 Then
    Dim n As Integer = Me.DataRepeater1.ItemCount
    For i As Integer = 1 To n
        Me.DataRepeater1.CurrentItemIndex = i - 1
        Dim item = Me.DataRepeater1.CurrentItem
        item.Controls("ImgListItem").ImageLocation = item.Controls("TxtImageLocation").Text
    Next
End If
```

Comment: Your image http://rental.joshblease.co.uk/propertyimages/image1.jpg throws a 404 error when I visit it.

Comment: @alstonp I am aware of that, the image name has been simplified for this case

Answer (score 1):

Simply add Picture Box property ImageLocation

```
ImgListItem.DataBindings.Add("ImageLocation", ListData, "FirstImage", True)
```

Answer (score 0):

The databinding for the image expects binary image data and in this case your passing it a string. What we can do is convert the image location into a format the binding can understand. Take a look at this link [C# Code Snippet - Download Image from URL](http://www.digitalcoding.com/Code-Snippets/C-Sharp/C-Code-Snippet-Download-Image-from-URL.html). Then once you have the image in memory, you will be able to bind it to your PictureBox.

Also, keep in mind that the simplest way shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11283212/windows-forms-how-to-directly-bind-a-bitmap-to-a-picturebox) would not work for you since [URIs are not supported by the BitMap class.](http://forums.asp.net/t/1316195.aspx)